# Hyperlinks on my website are not working

Tags: html

Just tried to make a little website from scratch (i'm a beginner) but weirdly my hyperlinks aren't working at the bottom of the page .. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.
Here is my code (couldn't paste it in here correctly sorry) : http://www.mediafire.com/view/bl7104l8q8plbvm/shutterbug.txt

Comment: Your link's 'href' attribute have no URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your link tags are:

```
<a href="#">Facebook</a>
```

A link with `href="#"` redirects to the current URL. Try changing it to:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if you found it helpful.